# 三角波を用いた変換に名前はあるのですか？

Tags: アルゴリズム

フーリエ変換のプログラムに矩形波を用いたものを[ウォルシュ・アダマール変換](http://who7s.blog.shinobi.jp/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0/%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%80%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B)と呼びますが、三角波を用いても変換ができると考えました。この三角波を用いたものにすでに名前はあるのですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackExchangeのSignal Processingに[類似する質問](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9020/dft-like-transform-using-triangle-waves-instead-of-sin-waves)がありました。  
三角波というよりのこぎり波のようですが`Slant Transform`というものがあるようです。